# Trying to write and get data back from file in C but only get last one infinitely (new to coding)

Tags: c, file

I have a task that i am asked to first write data to file after get that data back(account numbers names and balances) and print it.
I got writing part but i can't get all data back i get only last one infinite times. How can i get all one by one?

(and sorry for bad english ofc)

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int account;
    char name[50];
    double balance;

        FILE *cfPtr;
        char str[100];

        if((cfPtr=fopen("clients.dat","w"))==NULL)
        {
            printf("File could not be opened\n");
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Enter the account, name and balance.\n");
        printf("Enter EOF to end input.\n");
        printf("?");
        scanf("%d %s %lf", &account, name, &balance );
        while (!feof(stdin))
            {
            fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f \n", account, name, balance);
            printf("?");
            scanf("%d %s %lf", &account, name, &balance);
            }
            fclose(cfPtr);
        }     
        rewind(cfPtr);
        while(!feof(cfPtr))
        {
        fscanf(cfPtr,"%d %s %lf",&account, name, &balance);
        printf("%d %s %.2f",account,name,balance);      
        }
        return 0;
}
```

and compiling [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9xJu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with adding counter for each data input and looped last fscanf that times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int account;
    char name[50];
    double balance;
    int acc;
    char nam[50];
    double bal;
    int counter=0;
    int i;

        FILE *cfPtr;

cfPtr=fopen("clients.dat","w+");
                                            printf("Enter the account, name and balance.\n");
                                            printf("Enter EOF to end input.\n");
                                             printf("?");
        scanf("%d %s %lf", &account, name, &balance );
        while (!feof(stdin))
            {
            fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f \n", account, name, balance);
            printf("?");
            scanf("%d %s %lf", &account, name, &balance);
            counter++;
            }

            rewind(cfPtr);
                    printf("AccountNum       Name    Balance\n");
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++) {
            fscanf(cfPtr, "%d %s %lf", &acc, nam, &bal);
            printf("%10d %10s %10.2lf\n", acc, nam, bal);
        }
        fclose(cfPtr);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wold like to read and write to a file you should open it for reading and writing, for example:

```
fopen("clients.dat","w+"));  // notice "w+"
```

You shouldn't close a file if you plan do any operation after closing, it is mistake in this context:

```
    while(...)
    {
        ... 
        printf("?");
       scanf("%d %s %lf", &account, name, &balance);
    }
    fclose(cfPtr);       
   // you can't do any read-write operation with the file after fclose();
```